# How to show $\frac{|x-y||1-xy|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}<C|x-y|$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ any constant $C$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show $$\frac{|x-y||1-xy|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}<C|x-y|$$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ any constant $C$?

I can write upto $$\frac{|x-y||1-xy|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}<|x-y||1-xy|$$ as $1+x^2\geq 1$ and $1+y^2\geq 1$. But how to conclude?

Comment: If $x=y$,  the inequality doesn't hold. So $|x-y|$ isn't needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
|1-xy| \leq 1+|xy| \leq 1+x^2+y^2 \leq (1+y^2)(1+x^2).
\end{align}

Comment: so in fact, we can take $C=1$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yes.